# Where is the code that handles the API method catalogProductCreate?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, api

Can someone assist with finding the code that deals with the `catalogProductCreate` (SOAP v2) request?

I thought I found the method here: `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/api.php`

```
public function create($type, $set, $sku, $productData, $store = null)
```

But changing that file doesn't seem to do anything with the requests.

Comment: what about app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Api\V2.php ? don't forget to override it in a local folder..

Answer (score 3):

As commented by [@Anselme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/24233/anselme) the file you are looking for is `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php` as you are using the V2 variant of the API.

In that file there's the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2::create()` similar to the V1 API:

```
public function create($type, $set, $sku, $productData, $store = null)
```